# How to configure apache to work with FE and BE on same machine?

Tags: apache, configuration, server

I need to configure an apache server to serve a frontend and a backend (both php) from the same machine.
The following is to consider:

- The backend is RESTful and the API is secured by the firewall allowing only localhost access (only as temporary solution till API tokens are implemented).
- The frontend is on the same machine as backend at the moment, but will move to another server in some time.
- Static content will be delivered from the backend machine

My current configuration looks like following:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    NameVirtualHost *:81


        ServerName www.myServer.de

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /data/fe/public

        
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
        
        
                Options  FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                RewriteEngine On

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller...
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_fe.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_fe.log combined



ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot  /data/be/public

        
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
        
        
                Options  FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                RewriteEngine On

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller...
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_be.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_be.log combined
```

How can I configure the backend to serve static content without access limitation but keep the API secured. Or would it be an alternative to deliver static content through the application?

I'm using

- Debian 8.1
- Apache 2.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programing question.  It would probably be better at unix.stackexchange.com or super user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with configuring a reverse proxy for delivering static content. I added the following lines to my frontend vhost:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /images http://<BE-IP>:81/files/images
ProxyPassReverse /images http://<BE-IP>:81/files/images
```

With this configuration the backend is still guarded by the firewall from external requests but allows the FE to request images.